# How to give extra parameter with HQL join

Tags: mysql, select, join, hql

I would like to give extra parameter with join condition in hql.
In sql query I write

```
select a.*,ur.fname,ur.lname
from 
atom as a
left join user as ur
on 
a.id=ur.id
left join album as al
on 
a.id=al.aid
and al.name='Profile'
left join post_images as pi
on 
a.id=pi.aid
and pi.is_album_cover='yes'
where
(ur.fname like '%n%'
or ur.fname like '%n%')
and a.status='active';
```

which work propery and give desired result.
In hql I dont know how to give extra parameter with join
for fetching data  I write(without extra parameter)

```
feeds = (List<Atom>) session.createQuery(
             "select distinct atom from Atom as atom "
             + "left join fetch atom.albums  as album "
             + "left join fetch album.postImageses as coverImage "
             + "left join fetch atom.user as user "
             + "where "
             +  "(atom.user.fname like :name "
             + "or atom.user.lname like :name )"
              + "and album.name=:albumName "
             + "and coverImage.isAlbumCover=:isCover "
             + "and atom.status=:status ")
             .setParameter("albumName", "Profile")
             .setParameter("name", '%' + name + '%')
            .setParameter("name", '%' + name + '%')
             .setParameter("isCover", "yes")
             .setParameter("status", "active")
             .setFirstResult(0)
             .setMaxResults(30)
             .list();
```

Which is not giving any result how can I give extra parameter with join

Comment: You can print out the generated SQL and compare it to your working SQL. Btw, in SQL you have `a.status='active'`, but in hql you use `setParameter("status", "Active")` (upper cased first letter). Could that be a problem?

Comment: Same with `isCover` (`yes` and `Yes`)

Comment: I changed in question `setParameter("status", "active")'

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HQL, You may supply extra join conditions using the HQL with keyword.

Chech [**Associations and joins in HQL**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)

Try this:

Your **HQL::**

```
select distinct atom 
from Atom as atom 
left join atom.albums as album with album.name= "Profile" 
left join atom.postImageses as coverImage with coverImage.isAlbumCover="yes"
left join atom.user as user 
where (user.fname like name or user.lname like name) and atom.status="active";
```

Your **CODE::**

```
feeds = (List<Atom>) session.createQuery(
               "select distinct atom from Atom as atom "
             + "left join atom.albums as album with album.name=:albumName "
             + "left join atom.postImageses as coverImage with coverImage.isAlbumCover=:isCover "
             + "left join atom.user as user "
             + "where (user.fname like :name or user.lname like :name) "
             + "and atom.status=:status ")
             .setParameter("albumName", "Profile")
             .setParameter("name", '%' + name + '%')
             .setParameter("isCover", "yes")
             .setParameter("status", "active")
             .setFirstResult(0)
             .setMaxResults(30)
             .list();
```

Comment: It is showing `Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters`

Comment: Code is working but not giving appropriate result.  I want only coverImage of profile album.

Comment: @xrcwrn This query will give same result as your SQL gives if you want somwthing different then this then add sample input data with desired result to understand the exact issue

Comment: System.out.println(s.getSmallPicPath() + " " + s.getIsAlbumCover() + " " + s.getAlbum().getName() + " " + a.getId()); \n                                                    Below is 5 op                    `/img/post/small/8443098mubd4cp0e_1_yqf2vq5ns0141829_sm.jpg null Post 1
/img/post/small/0167466nvf535um2_1_bnmhihs6ux141829_sm.jpg null Post 1
/img/post/small/590235zttz3appmr_1_2clcp2e7oj141829_sm.jpg null Post 1`
`/img/post/small/732601ifkn7wod4r_1_p3tm1m2tta141931_sm.jpg null Post 1`
`/img/post/small/97237653xlptrp64_1_yeh6npsjj0141949_sm.JPG null Post 1`

Comment: @xrcwrn Please add sql fiddle demo for this so I can find what is the exact problem and provide you the solution

Comment: Hey one more thing I want to ask suppose I have to give one more parameter in with then like `with                coverImage.isAlbumCover="yes" and    coverImage.status="active"????

Comment: It is showing `Exception  org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements`

Comment: @xrcwrn It's right. You can add all conditions with `AND` in with part. But can add a condition which contain columnname on both side of condition. It must have value on one side

Comment: Tou have to add here - left join atom.postImageses as coverImage with coverImage.isAlbumCover=:isCover and coverImage.status="active"

Comment: @SaharshShah: Pls check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854216/org-hibernate-queryexception-unexpected-token-with-in-hql/38854356#38854356