# org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected token: WITH in hql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Hi am trying to join the tables with specific condition and when i executing the below query  and am getting the below error

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected token: WITH [
```

my HQL QUERY is below...

```
> List results1=session.createQuery("select financialDetail from
> FinancialDetail financialDetail " +
>                "left join financialDetail.financialClaimHeaderInfo fhdrinfo WITH (fhdrinfo.chk='224') "+
>                " where financialDetail.fc=:fc")
>                .setParameter("fc",fc)
>                .list();
```

In the financialDetail.hbm file i have a mapping between these two table like

> ```
> <set name="financialClaimHeaderInfo" table="F_CLM_HDR_TB" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="all" >
>           <key column="F_FCN_NUM" />
>           <one-to-many class="com.FinancialClaimHeaderInfo"/>
>       </set>
> ```

Pls guide me what is wrong here...

Comment: @RealSkeptic: i heard ON is not available in hibernate.thats why i used WITH

Comment: Is WITH a correct keyword ?
You should try to put 'fhdrinfo.chk='224'' into the where-condition:

where financialDetail.fc=:fc and fhdrinfo.chk='224'

Comment: my requirement is i need to get all the rows from financialDetail + rows from fhdrinfo where fhdrinfo.chk='224'

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put 'fhdrinfo.chk='224' into the where-condition.

```
 where financialDetail.fc=:fc and fhdrinfo.chk='224'
```